# How to get page wise DLL for my web application aspx pages in azure build pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

How to get page wise DLL for my web application aspx pages in azure build pipeline. While I run my pipeline its creating single build for my complete we application. But I want page wise dll for my web application.

I tried many ways in YAML file and classic editor tasks but could not get page wise dll.

```
- script: |
    for /r %%i in (*.aspx) do (
      echo Compiling page: %%i
      "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler" -v / -p "%%~dpi" -u -f -fixednames "output\%%~ni" 
      echo Compilation complete for: %%i
    )
  displayName: 'Compile ASPX Pages'
```

I had tried above script in yaml file and some other ways but getting

> ##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1' this error

I also tried MSBuild Arguments in publish build artifacts in azure pipeline but the issue remain same...

Comment: Can you get page wise DLL when build your project on your local VS? Would you please share your complete yaml file? If it's convenient, please share a sample project, so that I can test.

Answer (score 0):

To get page wise DLL for you web application aspx pages, you can refer to the below yaml file:

```
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '***'

- task: MSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '**/*.sln'
    msbuildArchitecture: 'x64'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v / -p $(Build.SourcesDirectory) -c -fixednames $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\TempBuildDir'

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\TempBuildDir\bin'
    artifact: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

In the CmdLine@2 task, use `-p` to specify the physical path of the application to be compiled. The output of `aspnet_compiler.exe` will be placed into `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\TempBuildDir`.

In PublishPipelineArtifact@1 task, set the `PublishPipelineArtifact@1` to the bin folder inside the output folder of `aspnet_compiler.exe`.

Then you can see the .dll files of your aspx pages in the pipeline artifact:
[image]

Comment: ##[error]The project file could not be loaded. Root element is missing. Error in MSBuild@1 

And in other Project 
/TestDemo1/About.aspx(1): error ASPPARSE: The file '/Site.Master' does not exist.
/TestDemo1/About.aspx(1): error ASPPARSE: Could not load type 'TestDemo1.About'.
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.

Please suggest..

Comment: 1. Can you successfully build your Webform project locally? 2. The information you have provided is limited at this time. Please share the yaml file you use. Also, please share a sample project so that I can test it on my side.

Comment: I had given YAML file as an answer...

Comment: The error “The project file could not be loaded. Root element is missing” in MSBuild typically indicates that the project file (.csproj) is not well-formed. So I want to confirm with you if you can build your solution/project successfully on your local machine using MSbuild.exe. If it failed locally, the error is related to your project. Tested with my project, there isn't any issue. It's suggested that you can share a sample project so that I can test from my side and provide more precise suggestions. Currently, it seems to be related to your project itself.